# Handling Alert Windows on Chrome Driver (Webdriver)

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

im having trouble handle ALert pop ups from Chrome, I keep getting the following error. org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: unexpected alert open
  (Session info: chrome=29.0.1547.66)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.3,platform=Windows NT 5.1 SP3 x86) .

Here is what i have tried so far. WHen i get to the page where the error is displayed:

```
driver.switchTo().alert.accept();
```

Also tried.

```
 Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
 alert.accept();
```

and also the same error.

If any got a solution for this it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be your ChromeDriver version. I wouldn't recommend always updating to the newest versions of something. Defects abound.

I'm using ChromeDriver win32_2.0 and it works fine. [Try that version.](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount+Release)

Answer (score 1):

Actually it(UnhandledAlertException) comes if you don't handle alert properly Otherwise, If you do any operation with driver instance before closing the alert.

Example

Step-1: Click Button     //this will lead to get an alert

Step-2: //Here you need to alert handle

In step-2 instead of handling alert if you do any other operation with driver instance it will throw UnhandledAlertException exception.

Comment: If cant use the driver instance how do I work with it? Becase i cant create an alert instance without using the driver isntance. This is the method i made to handle the alert

  public static boolean manejarAlertas(){
  boolean alerta = true;
  try {
   
   //Espero 10 segundo como maximo a que aparezca el mensaje de alert.
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
   driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
   //Si esta presente hago click en ok.
   //alert.accept();
  }catch (Exception e){
   alerta = false;
  }
  return alerta;
 }

Comment: Instead of WebDriverWait just give a try with static wait. I mean put some Thread.sleep(3000); and try the same. If it is working means we can think about wait logic.

Comment: Tried doing that and the problem persists, I even tried to use the ActionKey and press Key.Esc and its the same error.

Comment: Just curious , Have you tried with FirefoxDriver? Is it working fine?

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem with IE. But with two simple changes it started to work like under FF:
1)As suggested https://stackoverflow.com/a/20611297/2872258 I set another option while creating IEDriver - unexpectedAlertBehaviour=Ignore
2)I had also WebDriverWait for Alert, with setting ImplicityWait to "0" at the very beginning - according what @Santoshsarma said it was another problem.
Might be a solution as well for Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I tried catching the stackoverflow error and it worked for me as a workaround.

```
try
{   
    driver.findElement(By.xpath('xpath')).click(); // command that will trigger the alert window
}
catch (StackOverflowError e)
{
    driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss(); // or driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
    // the rest of the scripts can be added here
}
```